# How to join in JPA using foreign key directly?

Tags: java, jpa

Having two tables

```
A
 - id
 - name
 - bId

B
 - id
 - name
```

In the entity classes, because A is sent over a Webservice (in large amounts), I don't want to have B as a member of A. So the A-class does only have a member like that:

```
@Column(nullable=false)
private long bId;
```

Considering that, how can I retrieve a list with all A's referring to a B with name = X most effectively in JPQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select a from A a, B b
where a.bId = b.id
and b.name = :name
```

Note that A could have a toOne relationship to B marked as lazy, and configured (with transient?) so that it's not serialized by your Java to XML process.

Comment: Great. Sometimes the solution is easier than expected.

Comment: Yes, but what will be if there too many records in A and B? Wouldn't this cross join be much less efficient than inner join? If so, is rewriting entity model the only way to overcome this performance issue?

Comment: It's not a cross join, but a "manual" inner join, since there is a restriction on `a.bId = b.id`.